# How to use save() from JpaRepository in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have an interface that extends JpaRepository in kotlin.

```
interface EmployeeRepository: JpaRepository<Foo, Long>
```

I want to transform this java code.

```
FooRepository fooRepository;

public void callTheSave(){
    fooRepository.save(new Foo("Name","LastName"))
}
```

How i convert it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDEA comes with a nice Java -> Kotlin converter tool. I suggest using that for all  of these cases. Apart from that this is a pretty simple case:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var fooRepository: FooRepository

fun callTheSave(){
    fooRepository.save(Foo("Name","LastName"))
}
```

`@Autowired` and `lateinit` work together pretty well, Spring will be able to autowire your repository.